# How to set global options to Zend Filter LocalizedToNormalized (NormalizedToLocalized)

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, zend-form, zend-filter

I am using Zend Framework and LocalizedToNormalized and NormalizedToLocalized to make a localized form. The problem is in the whole application for example I want to use global options such as precision and number format.

One way I found is to create somewhere static instances of the filters, applied with options and use them everywhere I want, but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Zend_Locale and set an instance of it in the Zend_Registry so you could use it in the whole application. Remember that Zend_Registry is just like using a global var. It is not stored in a session or something like that.

Comment: I know how to use and use Zend_Locale and Zend_Registry, but the specifics of the application require exact precision of number format which can't be controlled by Zend_Locale itself. These filters accept locale and additional options - I want to make these additional options global.

Comment: For the case of number format, this is the best solution. For the case of precision, I think it would be a good idea to store at the bootstrap time, in the registry, a var which you can use everywhere.